# Efficient way to read first lines from several web files in C#

Tags: c#, web

There is a web server that contains several long files (>500Kb) with different categories of news. I only need to get the latest news in each category, first lines of the file (usually < 1Kb but can be more) and to make the download quick and because the connection is slow, my idea is to read line by line so downloading the minimum amount of data. At the moment I executing the below code but for the time it takes does not seem much improvement from downloading the full file.

```
foreach(var newsType in newsTypes)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.xxxx.com/" + newsType) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Timeout = 5000;
    using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var fileRowCSV = reader.ReadLine();
                ...
                if (old-news) break;
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there and setting I need to modify so not all the file gets transferred?
Can I reuse one connection in some way that can read the other files?
Any ideas on how to improve the process?

Thanks

Comment: You are downloading the whole file (though only reading the first line of the file).  You need a way to start the download but stop once the first new line is reached.  If the whole file will eventually be needed then you will want to resume where you left off downloading.  Not sure how to do this in .NET without using sockets (which would be a lot of work) but FreeDownloadManager (open source) does this and I think it is .NET.

Comment: NVM FreeDownloadManager is not .NET

Comment: I know new lines, the ones I want, are at the beginning of file. I need a way to specify in the request that only download a bit of the file and if more needed continue with another bit but don't know how to do it in a way that makes download go faster than downloading the full file.

Comment: I would give this question a day to see if anything useful comes.  If not then delete it and start a new question asking how to download a file until a new line is started.

Comment: In case you haven't already thought of it: You definitely should be doing this asynchronously on the server side (not with each page served). In other words, your server should retrieve the latest news periodically (10, 30, 60 minutes) and persist the current articles to be served with your pages. Your pages will then not depend on the external server or the wait involved to retrieve news. Further, if you find no easy solution to your question it will not be as large of an issue.

Comment: I know I could retrieve the news asynch and cache but my question is more how to transfer less data when required. The news files are updated in external server once per day ie. 10am. I want to read them fast after this update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this in the .NET Framework.  However, if you're looking to simply speed up the entire process, you can (relatively easily, I think) parallelize the outer `foreach` loop.

Alternatively, [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSWebDownloader-5fdcfb74) is an MSDN example that displays the progress of downloading a file from the web.  You should be able to use the code in that example to accomplish what you want: after every X bytes, check if you've reached `old-news` and, if so, cancel the download. Fair warning, it's not just a few lines of code.

Comment: Parallelize can save time if fast connection but if slow connection not saving much time if bottleneck is bandwidth. Look at the article and seems they play with the buffer size. Wonder if it can help doing:-  reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), true, 80)

Comment: Does the transfer stop is use StreamReader with a small buffer size?